# Zend Framework 2 Cronjob

Tags: php, mysql, email, cron, zend-framework2

I have a module that performs the CRUD on a library system. I have created an Action that emails me any new members added in the DB at the end of the day. But for that I have to run the Module application and go to that link for this to happen.

Can anyone tell me if I can do this without me clicking the link everytime or without even using the Application.

Whenever its 10pm... The actiion is triggered.. and I automatically get the email.

Comment: Sounds like you need a console route to your action, take a look at [this](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.console.introduction.html)

Answer (score 0):

That's a simple task that needs to be executed at provided time by given URL. Many hosting provides have installed the tool which is called "Cron". You'd simply need to find it and type an URL of your application that does the job and then add a time with your URL that triggers controller's action.

Assuming that `/foo/cron` triggers `FooController::cronAction` you'd simply define `/foo/cron` when adding a cron job to execute that action.

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget to use for this kind of requests the consoleview!

Normally you need no layout and another parts of the normal zf2 process.